# Starting ember server with ember cli

Tags: ember.js, ember-cli

Node Version - 0.10.26

Ember Cli version - 0.0.21

I have done

**ember new app**

On starting the server

**ember server**

Error!

```
Livereload server on port 31929
Serving on http://0.0.0.0:4200
EEXIST, file already exists 'tmp/merged_tree-tmp_dest_dir-DWy0VwmU.tmp/.bower.json'     Error: EEXIST, file already exists 'tmp/merged_tree-tmp_dest_dir-DWy0VwmU.tmp/.bower.json'
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:966:15)
at copyPreserveSync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli/node_modules/broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers/index.js:140:8)
at copyRecursivelySync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli/node_modules/broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers/index.js:129:5)
at copyRecursivelySync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli/node_modules/broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers/index.js:123:7)
at Object.linkRecursivelySync (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli/node_modules/broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers/index.js:153:30)
at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/broccoli/lib/merged_tree.js:24:19
at invokeCallback (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/commonjs/rsvp/promise.js:228:21)
at publish (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/commonjs/rsvp/promise.js:176:9)
at publishFulfillment (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/commonjs/rsvp/promise.js:312:5)
at flush (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ember-cli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/commonjs/rsvp/asap.js:41:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

I have also tried the same with ember cli version - 0.0.20

**node_modules/.bin/ember server**

```
Livereload server on port 31929
Serving on http://0.0.0.0:4200
EEXIST, file already exists 'tmp/merged_tree-tmp_dest_dir-4FjM03y6.tmp/.bower.json' Error: EEXIST, file already exists 'tmp/merged_tree-tmp_dest_dir-4FjM03y6.tmp/.bower.json'
at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:427:18)
at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:966:15)
at copyPreserveSync (/home/shrikanth/ember/donkey/node_modules/broccoli/node_modules/broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers/index.js:140:8)
at copyRecursivelySync (/home/shrikanth/ember/donkey/node_modules/broccoli/node_modules/broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers/index.js:129:5)
at copyRecursivelySync (/home/shrikanth/ember/donkey/node_modules/broccoli/node_modules/broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers/index.js:123:7)
at Object.linkRecursivelySync (/home/shrikanth/ember/donkey/node_modules/broccoli/node_modules/broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers/index.js:153:30)
at /home/shrikanth/ember/donkey/node_modules/broccoli/lib/merged_tree.js:24:19
at invokeCallback (/home/shrikanth/ember/donkey/node_modules/broccoli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/commonjs/rsvp/promise.js:228:21)
at publish (/home/shrikanth/ember/donkey/node_modules/broccoli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/commonjs/rsvp/promise.js:176:9)
at publishFulfillment (/home/shrikanth/ember/donkey/node_modules/broccoli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/commonjs/rsvp/promise.js:312:5)
at flush (/home/shrikanth/ember/donkey/node_modules/broccoli/node_modules/rsvp/dist/commonjs/rsvp/asap.js:41:9)
at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
at startup (node.js:119:16)
at node.js:902:3
```

Any suggesyion on where am I going wrong ?

Comment: I literally just encountered the same thing 10 minutes ago.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See this pull request https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-cli/pull/267 which is trying to fix recent changes to Broccoli https://github.com/joliss/broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers/issues/2

Comment: I just tried updating to ember cli 0.0.22, It works well without **"foundation": "5.1.1"** but when I add this                   Error: EEXIST, file already exists 'tmp/tree-tmp_dest_dir-OtU20N8g.tmp/fastclick.js'
EEXIST, file already exists 'tmp/tree-tmp_dest_dir-RuQp1s6f.tmp/fastclick.js'

Answer (score 0):

Did you try just deleting the tmp folder? I have had some issues with tmp files in the past, and deleting the folder and running ember init again usually helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try nuking your tmp, dist folders and retrying. If it still doesn't work nuke your node_modules folder as well followed by `npm install` and retrying `ember server`