# Ember-CLI error: file already exists

Tags: ember-cli, broccolijs

I am getting what looks to be a "classic" error when starting an Ember-CLI app:

`EEXIST, file already exists.`

I have consulted

[Starting ember server with ember cli](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22883936/starting-ember-server-with-ember-cli)

And it seems like the issue in Broccoli has been fixed?

I tried deleting the `node_modules` folder and the `tmp` folder, running `npm cache clear` then `npm install`.  But to no avail.

The weird thing is that there was *never* a file at templates/application.js (the reference file in the error below).

```
ember server

version: 0.1.5
Using `app.import` with a file in the root of `vendor/` causes a significant per
formance penalty. Please move `bower_components\modernizr\modernizr.js` into a s
ubdirectory.
Using `app.import` with a file in the root of `vendor/` causes a significant per
formance penalty. Please move `bower_components\fastclick\lib\fastclick.js` into
 a subdirectory.
Using `app.import` with a file in the root of `vendor/` causes a significant per
formance penalty. Please move `bower_components\foundation\js\foundation.js` int
o a subdirectory.
Livereload server on port 35729
Serving on http://0.0.0.0:4200/
EEXIST, file already exists 'C:\file-path\tmp\template_compil
er-tmp_dest_dir-0waBduix.tmp\ember-base\templates\application.js'
Error: EEXIST, file already exists 'C:\file-path\tmp\template
_compiler-tmp_dest_dir-0waBduix.tmp\ember-base\templates\application.js'
    at Object.fs.openSync (fs.js:432:18)
    at Object.fs.writeFileSync (fs.js:971:15)
    at Object.copyPreserveSync (C:\file-path\node_modules\emb
er-cli-emblem\node_modules\broccoli-emblem-compiler\node_modules\broccoli-filter
\node_modules\broccoli-kitchen-sink-helpers\index.js:150:8)
    at C:\file-path\node_modules\ember-cli-emblem\node_module
s\broccoli-emblem-compiler\node_modules\broccoli-filter\index.js:41:19
    at C:\file-path\node_modules\ember-cli-emblem\node_module
s\broccoli-emblem-compiler\node_modules\broccoli-filter\node_modules\promise-map
-series\index.js:11:14
    at $$$internal$$tryCatch (C:\file-path\node_modules\ember
-cli-emblem\node_modules\broccoli-emblem-compiler\node_modules\broccoli-filter\n
ode_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:490:16)
    at $$$internal$$invokeCallback (C:\file-path\node_modules
\ember-cli-emblem\node_modules\broccoli-emblem-compiler\node_modules\broccoli-fi
lter\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:502:17)
    at $$$internal$$publish (C:\file-path\node_modules\ember-
cli-emblem\node_modules\broccoli-emblem-compiler\node_modules\broccoli-filter\no
de_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:473:11)
    at Object.$$rsvp$asap$$flush [as _onImmediate] (C:\file-path\node_modules\ember-cli-emblem\node_modules\broccoli-emblem-compiler\node_mod
ules\broccoli-filter\node_modules\rsvp\dist\rsvp.js:1581:9)
    at processImmediate [as _immediateCallback] (timers.js:336:15)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the problem!

I was using `ember-cli-emblem` and I had *both* an `application.hbs` and a `application.emblem` in the templates folder.

Apparently this is not allowed, one must have one or the other.

Comment: This fixed it for me! I had both `app.coffee` and `app.js`. (I tried to debug by following https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-cli/issues/3413 -- but somewhere in the middle I decided to update ember, and it added a new `app.js` that I didn't notice.)